# Minecraft and ngrok server

Tags: minecraft

Every time that I reload the ngrok.exe it loads a different IP!
This can get really annoying if i'm trying to make a server with my friends. How do I fix this?

Comment: I take it that NGROK is something like a private VPN similar to Hamachii? You probably can't change it. Either use a service that allows you to have a group for you and your buddies, don't use a VPN and enable port forwards for the game to use your normal public IP or rent a server.

Answer (score 0):

Ngrok by design gives you a new address every time it runs. It's not meant to be a DNS. You could, however, use [ngrok link](https://ngrok.com/product/ngrok-link) as a workaround.

Comment: Please clarify and add a little more context to this answer to convey what you are suggesting exactly.